# Something's not quite right with my template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is something with this if statement? It works, just not correctly. No error comes up and it does display the number associated with each word value however it won't display the correct word and the front end.

```
<p class="accent list-text">I'm a:</p>
{% if request.user.userprofile.user_type == 1 %}
    <p class="profile-info list-text">Designer</p>
{% elif request.user.userprofile.user_type == 2 %}
    <p class="profile-info list-text">Designer</p>
{% else %}
    <p class="profile-info list-text">Both</p>
{% endif %}
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.choices import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',null=True,blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.userprofile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

choices.py:

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Designer")),
    (2, ("Developer")),
    (3, ("Both")),
)
```

Comment: Add your models.py

Comment: @AstikAnand Just added the models

Comment: Does it display anything in the template which is in the if condition?

Comment: Yes just not the right thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **UserProfile model**

Just use `CharField` for choices like this and it will work fine.

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Designer'),
    ('2', 'Developer'),
    ('3', 'Both'),
)

user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default='1')
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, I added my models and choices.py. `else` works and it displays "Both" but the other two choices seem to be confused

Comment: Hey I wanted to know if this worked for you or not??

Comment: Let me check it again. It caused an error with something else, but I think I know what it was.

Comment: @Garrett, If this solution helped you, please vote up and select the answer. Thanks a lot for all the cooperation.